# how to add a language in WMAppmanifest file for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Its easy to add multiple language support in Windows Phone 8.0 WMAppmanifest file, as it have a list of all languages to select from.....
But I dont find any field in 8.1 WMAppmanifest file to add support for multiple language because during app submission on store it says only English supported which is default language. I have added strings resources for different languages but need to find a way to add another language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [MSDN Contents of the package manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924767.aspx)  Section > **Resources**

By default it will only contain

```
<Resources>    
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
</Resources>
```

> The Resource Language token "x-generate" that's used in the source manifest file (package.appxmanifest) is replaced with the actual language code when the manifest is built.

So basically whatever language is the default language in in the manifest when editing it with the GUI.

If you want to add more languages then just add in another `Resource`

```
<Resources>    
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
    <Resource Language="en-us"/>
    <Resource Language="en-gb"/>
</Resources>
```

Comment: To be specific, `x-generate` is replaced with the language found in your `.csproj` file under `Project/PropertyGroup/DefaultLanguage`.

Comment: Is `x-generate` necessary? Isn't the list of supported languages of the app enough (or the correct, here)? And the 2 letter language codes are enough?