# Windows Phone Dashboard doesn't detect additional languages in my Windows Phone 8.1 app, only default

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store

My Windows Phone 8.1 application supports 2 languages and uses own localization system. I found 2 different ways to add the second language:

1) [how to add a language in WMAppmanifest file for Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027032/how-to-add-a-language-in-wmappmanifest-file-for-windows-phone-8-1) and

2) http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/22/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-localizing-apps/

I tried both:

1) edit Resources section in Package.appxmanifest

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="en-US" />
  <Resource Language="ru-RU" />
</Resources>
```

2) adding Strings folder with subfolders

```
Strings
  en-US
    Resources.resw
  ru-RU
    Resources.resw
```

but Windows Phone Dashboard doesn't detect any language besides default (en-US)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ensured that the phone you are testing with has both languages installed?

Your app may support more languages, but if you don't set up the phone/keyboard for that language it will just let the user access the language it can.

This tool might help https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit

Edit: also had to remember to not have empty resource files, need to have some (any) content in them to be found!

Comment: I am not testing on phone, I cannot add the second language in Windows Phone Dashboard ([link](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/overview)).

Comment: Are your resource files empty? This tool might help https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit

Comment: Wow, thanks! It was because of empty Resources.resw files. I added one string to each of them and now Windows store sees all my languages.